# Adobe Illustrator 8: trying to resize an image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, file-format

I forgot how to resize an image... I did look this up in the Help section, but was not able to find what I needed.

Comment: Use scale tool.

Comment: If you did not find [Scale, shear, and distort objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html) as the top result by searching for "adobe illustrator scale image" then you may need to update your google.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the image to select it, click & drag from any of the corners, holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> if you need a proportional resize.

[image]

Comment: Note those "hidden tools" are not present in **AI8** (If the user *actually* means 8). They were added at CC2014.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `View > Show Bounding Box` is on. Then merely click a corner handle and move it to resize an object.

The Bounding Box was a new feature in AI8 (circa 1998).

Or you can use the **Scale Tool** or simply double-click the Scale Tool in the tool bar to resize.

You can also use the menu -- `Object > Transform > Scale`

Or the **Free Transform Tool**, merely select the tool, grab an handle and move it.